# Push Buttons and Tabbed Canvas

Tags: oracleforms

I Have made a form which contains only a tabbed Canvas with three tabs each tab has one data block, I Have also one button which is the Exit button that belongs to one tab (It's not optional from what I see, I have to make the button belongs to one of the three tabs or more specifically to one of the three data blocks).
My problem is that the button will not be displayed when I run the form Unless I Do something with the tab that it belongs to.
But I want it to be displayed unconditionally.
Is there any way to make the button belongs to the Empty Content Canvas
instead of the tab canvas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out, Indeed the button should belongs to a data block, so I made an empty new block inside the Content Canvas and made the button belongs to it.